# Apple no longer accepts submissions of apps that use QuickTime or QTKit APIs of Electron App

Tags: macos, electron

I received the following e-mail from Apple.

```
 Deprecated API Usage - Apple no longer accepts submissions of apps that use QuickTime or QTKit APIs.
 Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the corrected binary.
```

I am using the Electron, and has registered the application by the here reference.

https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/mac-app-store-submission-guide.md

How to find a QuickTime or QTKit, Is there a way to remove it?

I used 0.34.3 of Electron
and I used this repository.

https://github.com/atom/electron-quick-start

build shell is here.

```
#! /bin/bash

APP="HogeApp"
APP_ID="com.md-note.HogeApp"
APP_PATH="HogeApp.app"
FRAMEWORKS_PATH="$APP_PATH/Contents/Frameworks"
APP_KEY="3rd Party Mac Developer Application: Xxx Yyy (XXXXXXXXX)"
INSTALLER_KEY="3rd Party Mac Developer Installer: Xxx Yyy (XXXXXXXXX)"
APP_VERSION="1.0.3"

electron-packager ./build/electron HogeApp --overwrite --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --version=0.34.3 --asar=true --icon=./build/electron/assets/icon.icns

sed -i -e "/<key>CFBundleIdentifier<\/key>/N;s#\(<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>.*<string>\).*\(</string>\)#\1${APP_ID}\2#" "./HogeApp-darwin-x64/HogeApp.app/Contents/Info.plist"
sed -i -e "/<key>CFBundleShortVersionString<\/key>/N;s#\(<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>.*<string>\).*\(</string>\)#\1${APP_VERSION}\2#" "./HogeApp-darwin-x64/HogeApp.app/Contents/Info.plist"
sed -i -e "/<key>CFBundleVersion<\/key>/N;s#\(<key>CFBundleVersion</key>.*<string>\).*\(</string>\)#\1${APP_VERSION}\2#" "./HogeApp-darwin-x64/HogeApp.app/Contents/Info.plist"
sed -i -e "/<key>CFBundleIdentifier<\/key>/N;s#\(<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>.*<string>\).*\(</string>\)#\1${APP_ID}.helper.EH\2#" "./HogeApp-darwin-x64/HogeApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/HogeApp Helper EH.app/Contents/Info.plist"
sed -i -e "/<key>CFBundleIdentifier<\/key>/N;s#\(<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>.*<string>\).*\(</string>\)#\1${APP_ID}.helper.NP\2#" "./HogeApp-darwin-x64/HogeApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/HogeApp Helper NP.app/Contents/Info.plist"
sed -i -e "/<key>CFBundleIdentifier<\/key>/N;s#\(<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>.*<string>\).*\(</string>\)#\1${APP_ID}.helper\2#" "./HogeApp-darwin-x64/HogeApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/HogeApp Helper.app/Contents/Info.plist"

rm "./HogeApp-darwin-x64/HogeApp.app/Contents/Info.plist-e"
rm "./HogeApp-darwin-x64/HogeApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/HogeApp Helper EH.app/Contents/Info.plist-e"
rm "./HogeApp-darwin-x64/HogeApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/HogeApp Helper NP.app/Contents/Info.plist-e"
rm "./HogeApp-darwin-x64/HogeApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/HogeApp Helper.app/Contents/Info.plist-e"

rm -rf "./HogeApp-darwin-x64/HogeApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Resources/crashpad_handler"
rm -rf "./HogeApp-darwin-x64/HogeApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Libraries"
rm -rf "./HogeApp-darwin-x64/HogeApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/Squirrel.framework/Resources/ShipIt"
rm -rf "./HogeApp-darwin-x64/HogeApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/HogeApp Helper EH.app"
rm -rf "./HogeApp-darwin-x64/HogeApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/HogeApp Helper NP.app"


cd HogeApp-darwin-x64

codesign --deep -fs "$APP_KEY" --entitlements ../macosx/child.plist "$FRAMEWORKS_PATH/Electron Framework.framework/Libraries/libnode.dylib"
codesign --deep -fs "$APP_KEY" --entitlements ../macosx/child.plist "$FRAMEWORKS_PATH/Electron Framework.framework/Electron Framework"
codesign --deep -fs "$APP_KEY" --entitlements ../macosx/child.plist "$FRAMEWORKS_PATH/Electron Framework.framework/"
codesign --deep -fs "$APP_KEY" --entitlements ../macosx/child.plist "$FRAMEWORKS_PATH/$APP Helper.app/"
#codesign --deep -fs "$APP_KEY" --entitlements ../macosx/child.plist "$FRAMEWORKS_PATH/$APP Helper EH.app/"
#codesign --deep -fs "$APP_KEY" --entitlements ../macosx/child.plist "$FRAMEWORKS_PATH/$APP Helper NP.app/"
codesign --deep -fs "$APP_KEY" --entitlements ../macosx/parent.plist HogeApp.app

productbuild --compone`enter code here`nt "HogeApp.app" /Applications --sign "$INSTALLER_KEY" "HogeApp.pkg"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is corrected in the latest version of the MAS version of Electron, just update and resubmit

Comment: Thank you.
I was doing in 0.34.1. We'll try 0.34.3.

Comment: Are you 100% sure you're using the MAS (Mac App Store) version of Electron and not the ad-hoc version?

Comment: I think that it is there.

app version is displayed Hello world.

We are using node 4.1.1, Chrome 45.0.2454.85, and Electron 0.34.3